# Generating complex legend with specific layout using Python script in ArcMap or ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, arcgis-pro, legend

#### Aim

I need to generate complex legend with specific layout using Python script. Either using built-in legend / graphic elements or generating features in new geodatabase and data frame. It is possible to use other software (Adobe Illustrator/Indesign) for final composition.

#### Introduction & data structure

I'm architect and I make urban plans for villages/towns. I create few urban plans per year.

For each urban plan I have six `.mxd` files with tens to hundreds of layers with specific complex symbology which is provided by our regional authority. I always use the same template with same (almost) layers and with same digital model in `.fgdb`.

Depending on data in each village there are some layers without connected feature class (if there are no data available in specific feature class the regional authority doesn't provide it). Layers are grouped in group layers.

**I have to create legend with specific layout for each visible feature in each layer.** I've always created legend manually in Adobe Indesign after exporting maps from ArcMap. But it is very time-consuming and ineffective way.

**Symbology in each layer is based on attribute `ENTITA_ID` which is combination of other three attributes:**

```
ENTITA_ID = JEV_ID & STAV_ID & TOPO_ID

JEV_ID = 6 DIGIT NUMBER | Each layer/feature class contains few JEV_IDs - each for one specific feature.
STAV_ID = 1 DIGIT NUMBER | State of feature - There are two main states (1=existing, 2=proposed) and few other.
TOPO_ID = 1 DIGIT NUMBER | 1/2/3 - always same for whole layer.
```

#### I need to create legend with specific layout.

In each row should be all features with same JEV_ID but different STAV_IDs (1, 2, opt. 3 or 9). I'd prefere also showing lables over legend items (if the LABELS are visible).

"Symbology label" could be imported from some xls/txt/csv (or any other) file. It is always same for same JEV_ID. It could be found partially also in layer symbology settings under symbol label with appended state after dash (" - ").

**I need to show only JEV_IDs which are visible in map extent (it usually means all data from feature class).**

| SYMBOLOGY LABEL | STAV_ID = 1 | STAV_ID = 2 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Feature 1 label | State 1 of Feature 1 (legend based on ENTITA_ID) | State 2 of Feature 1 (legend based on ENTITA_ID) | ... |
| Feature 2 label | State 1 of Feature 2 (legend based on ENTITA_ID) | State 2 of Feature 2 (legend based on ENTITA_ID) | ... |
| Feature 3 label | State 1 of Feature 3 (legend based on ENTITA_ID) | State 2 of Feature 3 (legend based on ENTITA_ID) | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

## Possible solutions / ideas

### Generate graphic elements

- no idea how to solve this
- **Could you describe simple / complex steps or pieces of code to achieve this?**

### Generate new features in new file geodatabase and dataframe

**My idea:**

1. Create legend.fgdb
2. List all visible layers
3. Create feature class for each visible layer
4. List all unique JEV_IDs in each original feature class
5. Create rectangular polygon (line / point) feature for each unique JEV_ID in specified position

x. Export features

- no idea how to add symbology label next to created features
- **Do you think it will be working solution?**
- **What exact steps shoud I do?**

**Which one is better? Are there better solutions? Any idea?**

### Available software

- ArcMap 10.8.1
- ArcGIS Pro (latest version)
- *Adobe Illustrator*
- *Adobe Indesign*

[image: Legend layout]

Comment: I think you should focus your question on ArcGIS Pro, and ask a separate question about ArcMap, because answers to your question are unlikely to apply to both. I think your best chance of an answer is with ArcGIS Pro which has CIM access from ArcPy.

Comment: As per the [Tour] there should be only one question asked per question.